# Does conn.SetDeadline() close the connection if it times out

Tags: go

I have a Golang project that utilizes conn.SetDeadline(). If a an EOF error is thrown because a read timed out, does Go automatically close the connection?

I have a setup where I need to wait a certain amount of time on a network connection for output to arrive, and if the output doesn't arrive, then it has to send a QUIT command. I haven't designed the network application, so redesigning the protocol isn't an option

Ideally, when an EOF is thrown because of SetDeadline timing out, then I would want the goroutine to awaken, but not for the connection to close

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't. My workaround (well, not workaround, but the correct way to do this) was like so

```
timeout := make(chan error)
buf := make([]byte, 32)
go func() {
    _, err := conn.Read(buf)
    timeout <- err
}()
select {
case time.After(time.Now() + 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 5): // Wait for 5 seconds
    // Timed out reading
    go func() {
        <-timeout // We have to read from the sem to prevent mem leaks
    }()
case err := <-timeout:
    // Successfully read
}
```